# Display in the list of website articles the tree of categories Odoo

Tags: xml, menu, odoo

I want to display in the list of website articles the tree of categories
I tried with this source code but it just shows me the last categories

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
 <li t-if="category"><a t-att-href="keep('/shop',category=0)" t-field="category.name"/></li>

 <li t-if="category">
<a t-att-href="keep('/shop/category/' + slug(category), category=0)"
                   t-field="category.name"/>
</li>  

                </ol>

                <ol>
  <li t-if="category.child_id" t-attf-class="text-primary fa #{'fa-chevron-down' if category.id in parent_category_ids else 'fa-chevron-right'}">
      <a t-att-href="keep('/shop/category/' + slug(category), category=0)" t-field="category.name"></a>

  </li>


                </ol>


            </div>


          </div>
```

I want a result like pictures
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find the solution in this module

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/website_breadcrumb/

you can add this template in website module xml file

this the true code XML

```html
    <template id="breadcrumb" name="Breadcrumb snippet">
        <!-- Know if current page is in a menu item -->
        <t t-set="bc_item"
           t-value="request.env['website.menu']
                    .search([('url', '=', request.httprequest.path)], limit=1)"/>
    
        <!-- If so, create the breadcrumbs -->
        <ol t-if="bc_item" class="breadcrumb">
            <!-- Parents -->
            <t t-foreach="bc_item.get_parents(True)" t-as="step">
                <li t-if="step.url or step_first">
                    <a t-att-href="step.url or (step_first and '/')">
                        <t t-if="step_first and not step.url">
                            Home
                        </t>
                        <t t-if="not step_first and step.url">
                           <t t-esc="step.name_get()[0][1]"/>
                       </t>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </t>
    
            <!-- Current -->
            <li class="active" t-esc="bc_item.name_get()[0][1]"/>
        </ol>
    </template>
```

thank

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.